# How to call to the "next" function, using angular ui calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using the angular ui calendar, and as all, i have the next and previus buttons, and i click on the button and it works, it change the month, but i need to add another code when i click i that button, i tried to call with this:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.fc-next-button', function() {
//do something
});
```

and it did not work

Comment: sorry i am new and i posted that rectangle

Comment: Share your calendar code please. Apart from that, try to avoid using jQuery incorporated with Angular

Comment: Please post the controller code where you wrote this event handler. Generally the click event handler should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope You are talking about fullcalendar.

Try this one:

```
   $('#my-next-button').click(function() {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
   });
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="next()">Next button</button>
```

**JS**
Add this in your Angular code. On clicking the button, this function will be called.

```
$scope.next= function(){
       // your code
    },
```